# Parallelization is not doing what expected

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to zoom an image, optimizing it via OpenMP. In order to do so, I'm using the bicubic interpolation, so as it has to be done for every color RGB, I decided that doing each color in a section would be a nice idea:

```
CImg<unsigned char> img // JPG Image of 254x254
int zFactor //Zoom factor, in this case using 4
unsigned char arr[4][4];
unsigned char color[3];
unsigned char tmp_color0, tmp_color1, tmp_color2;
for(i=0; i<z_img.width(); i++) {
    for(j=0; j<z_img.height(); j++) {
        //For R,G,B
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for(l=0; l<4; l++){
                        for(k=0; k<4; k++){

                            arr[l][k] = img(i/zFactor +l, j/zFactor +k, 0, 0); // img (x,y,z,c)
                        }
                    }
                    tmp_color0   = bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, (unsigned char)(i%zFactor)/zFactor, (unsigned char)(j%zFactor)/zFactor);
                }
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for(l=0; l<4; l++){
                        for(k=0; k<4; k++){

                            arr[l][k] = img(i/zFactor +l, j/zFactor +k, 0, 1); // img (x,y,z,c)
                        }
                    }
                    tmp_color1   = bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, (unsigned char)(i%zFactor)/zFactor, (unsigned char)(j%zFactor)/zFactor);
                }
                #pragma omp section
                {
                    for(l=0; l<4; l++){
                        for(k=0; k<4; k++){

                            arr[l][k] = img(i/zFactor +l, j/zFactor +k, 0, 2); // img (x,y,z,c)
                        }
                    }
                    tmp_color2   = bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, (unsigned char)(i%zFactor)/zFactor, (unsigned char)(j%zFactor)/zFactor);
                }
        }
        color[0]=tmp_color0;
        color[1]=tmp_color1;
        color[2]=tmp_color2;
        z_img.draw_point(i,j,color);
    }
}
```

Where bicubicInterpolate_paralelo is a function that computes the bicubic interpolation of a pixel. Running this code, I obtain the following result:
[image: Xiaomi_logo_zoomed]

It is clear I'm ignoring a dependency of color with the temporal color variables, but I how could I solve it? Without using OpenMP it is working perfectly, so it is problem of OpenMP implementation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: add `private( arr, l, k )` to your `parallel` directive

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `arr` array for all of your threads.  Either use separate arrays (declared within the sections), or redo your threading to run threads on your outer for loop and not the internal ones.

If your image is laid out in the usual fashion your performance would be better to have the `y` loop as the outer loop (since this would better utilize the memory cache).

Comment: Using separate `arr` arrays for each section is not solving the problem, I guess because it can reach `tmp_color` before finishing all of them. Is there any way to solve that dependency? Thanks for the answer! @1201ProgramAlarm